# R - How to delete rows by a value, when NAs are present

Tags: r, row, na

I am really struggling with removing a set of rows from my dataset in R.

I have a data frame as follows:

```
ID    col1   sp  
R1    1.2    F  
R2    2.35   F   
R3    5      NA  
R4    4.3    NA    
R5    2.22   T  
R6    1.35   F
```

I want to remove row `R5`, based on the fact it has a `T` in the sp column. But I DON'T want it to remove the rows with `NA` (i.e. rows R3 and R4) as I still need the data in `col1`!

The code I used:

```
data1<-subset(data,sp!="T")
```

But that also removes all the rows with `NA` in the `sp` column (`ID`s R3, R4 and R5). I also tried:

```
data1<-subset(data,sp!="T",na.rm=FALSE)
```

But this still removed all three rows - I only want to remove the one with "T" in column "sp". I can't figure it out, and have searched but cannot find an answer to this specific problem. Any help would be brilliant, as I have 1000+ rows and do not was be going through removing them manually! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `which()` command does not display the problem that the subset command has.  For example,

```
ID = c("R1","R2","R3","R4","R5","R6")
col1 = c(1.2,2.35,5,4.3,2.22,1.35)
sp = c("F","F",NA,NA,"T","F")

data = data.frame(ID,col1,sp)
data1 = data[-which(data$sp=="T"),]
```

Which yields:

```
> data
  ID col1   sp
1 R1 1.20    F
2 R2 2.35    F
3 R3 5.00 <NA>
4 R4 4.30 <NA>
5 R5 2.22    T
6 R6 1.35    F


> data1
  ID col1   sp
1 R1 1.20    F
2 R2 2.35    F
3 R3 5.00 <NA>
4 R4 4.30 <NA>
6 R6 1.35    F
```

Just to make sure you fully understand, `which()` finds the indices of where T is in the vector sp, i.e.,

```
> which(data$sp=="T")
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of dealing with this is to use the `%in%` operator:

```
data[!(data$sp %in% "T"),]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a combination of the function `is.na` and the OR (`|`) operator:

```
data1[!data1$sp | is.na(data1$sp),]
```

Using subset notation:

```
subset(data1, !sp | is.na(sp))
```